# Trouble with radio buttons and show/hide functionality in sidetmap tree in React

Tags: reactjs, tree, radio-button, state, hierarchy

I'm working on a tree view in which I have three radio buttons for different levels of the tree: first level, second level, and third level. I'm also trying to implement a functionality where, when I click on a particular node, only its child nodes are displayed.

The issue I'm having is that these two functionalities don't seem to be working together properly. Either one works fine on its own, but when I try to switch between radio buttons while also trying to show/hide child nodes of a particular node, things don't work as expected.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import frontendroadmap from "./json";
import { useState } from "react";



function Category({ category, level, onCategoryClick }) {

  const [showSubcategories, setShowSubcategories] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    onCategoryClick(level);
    setShowSubcategories(!showSubcategories);
  };

  return (
    <li className='roadmap_li'>
      <span className='roadmap_span' onClick={handleClick}>
        {category.name}
      </span>
      {showSubcategories && category.subcategories && (
        <ol className='roadmap_ol'>
          {category.subcategories.map((subcategory, index) => (
            <Category
              key={index}
              category={subcategory}
              level={level + 1}
              onCategoryClick={onCategoryClick}
            />
          ))}
        </ol>
      )}
    </li>
  );
}





export const App= () => {
  const [selectedLevel, setSelectedLevel] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedLevel(1);
  }, []);

  const handleLevelChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedLevel(parseInt(event.target.value));
  };

  const handleCategoryClick = (level) => {
    setSelectedLevel(level + 1);
  };

  const radioData = [
    { id: 1, name: 'First level', value: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Second level', value: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Third level', value: 3 },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1 className='roadmap-radio-title'>Category Sitemap</h1>
        <span className='display'>Show: </span>
        {radioData.map((radio) => (
          <React.Fragment key={radio.id}>
            <input
              checked={selectedLevel === radio.value}
              data-tooltip={`level ${radio.value}`}
              id={`roadmap_level_${radio.value}_rbtn`}
              name='test'
              type='radio'
              value={radio.value}
              onChange={handleLevelChange}
            />
            <label
              className='roadmap_level_rbtn_name'
              htmlFor={`roadmap_level_${radio.value}_rbtn`}
            >
              {radio.name}
            </label>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}

        <ol className='wtree roadmap_ol '>
          {frontendroadmap.map((category, index) => (
            <Category
              key={index}
              category={category}
              level={1}
              onCategoryClick={handleCategoryClick}
            />
          ))}
        </ol>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what's going wrong here. How can I get these two functionalities to work together properly?

Thanks in advance for your help!

here is the live working example of code sandbox for your reference...
https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-fire-djbn4v?file=/src/App.js